# Formatting XAxis labels when rendering chart on server using phantomjs and JSON

Tags: json, highcharts, phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs to render png images of a highchart using a json file from a commandline script.
As it's JSON obviously I can't using the xAxis.labels.formatter as I would in a web client version, but as these are for automated reports we don't want to have to generate them through a browser.

Is there anyway of formatting the xAxis labels to be something like the result of:

> Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%y %H:%M',this.value)

Currently they are showing up as what I assume is the default. e.g. 10 Feb

This doesn't even tell us what year it is.

I'm using the default "highcharts-convert.js" file as the first parameter to phantomjs
Second paramater is my highcharts configuration as a json object
Third is the name of the output file

Is it possible to do it in the callback script if so how would I pass a function to the formatter?

I've tried iterating over the collection of labels but this didn't work:

```
function(chart) {
    $.each( chart.xAxis.labels, function( index, value ){
        chart.xAxis.labels[index] = Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%y %H:%M',value);
    });
}
```

Or are there any other alternatives that are open to me?

Comment: Why can you not use the formatter as you normally would?

Comment: Because the chart options and series are all sent in JSON format and you can't include javascript functions in JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use [`xAxis.labels.format`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.format), see [more info](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting).

And [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/PwEnd/) from docs.

Comment: I looked at the first reference you mention but then when you click on the "format string" link it goes to a 404. I guess it should go to the second link you mention, which I missed. This is what I was after though so thanks.

Comment: Yeah, URL in docs is broken (will be fixed) that's why I send you second one. Good luck!